# Add only changes in content (don't replace all content) to live-preview (with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, preview

Imagine a preview feature where every time something is typed in an editable `<div>` box, its content is displayed in a preview `<div>`box. Minimum example:

```js
jQuery('div#edit').keyup(function() {
  var a = jQuery(this).html();
  jQuery('div#preview').html(a);
});
```

```css
#edit {
  border: solid 1px #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contentEditable="true" id="edit">Type here...</div>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

This example replaces the **entire** `#preview`-content with the **entire** `#edit`-content. Instead of replacing everything, I would like to only add/remove those specific characters that are **different**.

Meaning, when the content is fetched at a key stroke and stored in the variable `a`, I'd like to compare `a` to the content of the preview box

- and filter out only the **differences between them**.
- Then I want **these differences added to the preview box** (at the correct locations in the already existing preview string).

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible, but it would involve some non-trivial DOM parsing

Comment: if do that, maybe performance will have issue, think about this, you need to monitor keyboard event, and also you need to know cursor position, and make logic more complex, like you need take care about copy paste, delete event etc, can I know why you dont want just replace all?